# How can I set the Juniper EX3300 Switch's Interface traffic speed?

Tags: juniper, juniper-junos, juniper-ex

How can I set the Juniper EX3300 Switch's Interface traffic speed?

Before asking this question I have attempted many methods, all fail.

first of all, set the Interface traffic speed is not the [interfaces speed doc](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/speed-interfaces-ex-series.html), because this only can set `10m, 100m, 1g`.

I want to let the `ge-0/0/0` input and output can limit speed to `23m`.

My device is `EX3300`, how can I set it?

Now my configurations is this:

**firewall**

```
firewall {
    family ethernet-switching {
        filter lnterface-Police {
            term Police {
                from {
                    source-address {
                        0.0.0.0/0;
                    }
                }
                then policer limit-50m;
            }
            term Permit-ALL-Other {
                then accept;
            }
        }
    }
    policer limit-50m {
        if-exceeding {
            bandwidth-limit 20m;
            burst-size-limit 1500;
        }
        then discard;
    }
}
```

**ge-0/0/5**

```
ge-0/0/5 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            filter {
                input lnterface-Police;
                output lnterface-Police;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but when I use `commit check`, there gets bellow error:

```
admin# commit check
[edit interfaces ge-0/0/10 unit 0 family ethernet-switching]
  'filter'
    Referenced filter 'lnterface-Police' can not be used as policer not supported on egress
error: configuration check-out failed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use L3/L4 ACL options in L2 ACL's, and also EGRESS policing is not supported.

Here working example for you:

```
[edit interfaces ge-5/0/46 unit 0 family ethernet-switching]
       filter {
           input interface-police;
       }

[edit firewall]
    family ethernet-switching {
        filter interface-police {
            term limit-50m {
                then policer limit-50m;
            }
        }
    }

[edit firewall]
   policer limit-50m {
       filter-specific;
       if-exceeding {
           bandwidth-limit 50m;
           burst-size-limit 15k;
       }
       then discard;
   }
```

In this case policer will only limit INGRESS traffic. To limit also EGRESS traffic add this section:

```
[edit]
  class-of-service {
      interfaces {
          ge-5/0/46 {
              shaping-rate 50m;
          }
      }
  }
```

**Update**

I was wrong. CoS applied only for interface output, so CoS shaping and input policing should be both applied.

Comment: You write the `shaping-rate 50m;` but you  set `policer limit-50m `. do you mean we can write the `50m ` directly which mean 50 M bits? or you write wrong there?

Comment: @aircraft, In CoS for shaping you specifying exact number of bits you need. In this case 50m equals to 50000000 bits/s. You can shrink values, yes. Policer and CoS is a for different things.

Comment: I have a question now, how can I know the limit configuration works? Is there a tool for checking bandwidth? or is there a property of switch port to show the bandwidth?

Comment: If you have internet access from station connected to that port, you can simply run speedtest. Other option is to transfer some data between two stations in your network. You can track current load on interface with `show interface ge-0/0/0 extensive`

Comment: I have connected to that port, can you explain speedtest more? or give a link for its usage.

Comment: It's a web service for testing internet speed. https://speedtest.net

Comment: test the dedicated server should use the server for open the speediest.net, right?

Comment: On a host behind port on what you've set bandwidth limit, open speedtest in a browser. If you have internet link more than 50 Mbps (and that is actually required to test your shaping with this method) and all is configured properly, your speed will be just around 50 Mbps.

Comment: Hi, friend, I follow those steps to limit a Switch port, it works when I limit one or two ports, but if limit more than 5 , then the ports who limited the speed will have packet loss problem.

Answer (score 1):

Try shaping your egress traffic - you can't police it.

add this to shape your egress traffic:

```
[edit class-of-service interfaces]
ge-0/0/5 {
    shaping-rate 23m;
}
```

remove `output lnterface-Police;` from your ge-0/0/5 interface config.

and try committing again.

Comment: Do you mean I do not care the firewall's configuration, set the `shaping-rate xxm` directly in the `class-of-service interfaces ge-0/0/5`?

Comment: I'm assuming you want 23 Mb/s in and out - you need to police ingress, and shape egress.

i.e. 
ge-0/0/5 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            filter {
                input lnterface-Police;
                output lnterface-Police;
            }
        }
    }
}

must be 

ge-0/0/5 {
    unit 0 {
        family ethernet-switching {
            filter {
                input lnterface-Police;
            }
        }
    }
}
and add the class-of-service stanza.

Comment: @Discus, my apologies. Made edit to my post.

Comment: @Discus Hi, Discus, I follow those steps to limit a Switch port, it works when I limit one or two ports, but if limit more than 5 , then the ports who limited the speed will have packet loss problem.

Comment: Packet loss is ultimately how shaping works... 
Once you go over rate X for beyond the burst limit time, packets *must* be lost. 
If you increase the limits, does the packet loss resolve?

It *should* be done in PFE, iirc, but check that it's not CPU bound as well.