# How to check the Juniper Switch's port bandwidth?

Tags: juniper, bandwidth, juniper-ex

I use the [CoS method](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53416/38050) limited the EX3300's switch port bandwidth to `200m`.

But I have a question, how to check whether it works?
Is there the Juniper Switch EX3300's switch port have a bandwidth property intuitively? or should I use a tool in the Dedicated Server for checking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in previous question, you can check that shaping is working by transfering data to target (shaped) host by either copying something (via NetBIOS, SCP/FTP, etc.) or by running simple speedtest ([link](https://speedtest.net)).
Interface statistics can be retrieved by running `> show interface ge-0/0/0 extensive | match bps`

Here is example. Target host interface shaped under CoS section to 50 Mbps limit.

```
set class-of-service interfaces ge-5/0/13 shaping-rate 50m
```

I'm then started speedtest on target computer to check results.
Here is speed results without shaping:
[image]

After shaping applied:
[image]

Interface statistics:
[image]