# I limit the port INGRESS but get packet loss

Tags: switch, juniper, qos

I use the [limit speed method](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/53416/38050) to limit the Juniper Switch port  EGRESS and INGRESS speed.

but after I added the INGRESS filter to my port, there will loss packets on the switch every port.

anybody know how to do with this?

---

Edit-01:

```
admin@1402A# run show configuration class-of-service                            
interfaces {                                                                    
    ge-0/0/19 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 200m;                                                      
    }                                                                           
    ge-0/0/14 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 200m;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    ge-0/0/36 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 50m;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    ge-0/0/40 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 50m;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    ge-0/0/42 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 50m;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    ge-0/0/43 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 50m;                                                       
    }                                                                           
    ge-0/0/47 {                                                                 
        shaping-rate 50m;                                                       
    }                                                                           
}
```

Comment: Can you paste in the output of `show configuration class-of-service`

Comment: You mean packet loss on ports configured for policing or on **every** port?

Comment: Yes, I have found the issue.

Comment: You should accept your answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Comment: the accept time is not reach at now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found the issue :

```
[edit firewall]
   policer limit-50m {
       filter-specific;
       if-exceeding {
           bandwidth-limit 50m;
           burst-size-limit 15k;
       }
       then discard;
   }
```

from [document](https://www.juniper.net/documentation/en_US/junos/topics/reference/configuration-statement/burst-size-limit-edit-firewall-policer.html):

`burst-size-limit` unit is `byte`, so I set it to `13m`, it becomes fine.

Comment: Remember to accept your answer when you can. :-)